# Automated Check box population within Salesforce from Checking a Box w/in DocuSign

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Is there a code built that I can use to automate a check box field to populate w/in Salesforce from Checking a Check box field w/in a DocuSign agreement?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You will need the checkbox field created in Salesforce under the object. Once that's done you can go into DocuSign and create a custom tag and relate it back to the field in SFDC. If checked on the sent DocuSign envelope it will check the field in SFDC and vice versa.

Info can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/support/salesforce/documentation/dfs-user-guide/user-guide/create-merge-fields-user)