# Is it possible to dynamically add updateable custom tags to documents?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

Background: 
I just started researching on DocuSign a couple days back and was told by DocuSign Customer Support to post questions here on SO. I am running a trial version of DocuSign to evaluate the capabilities and see if it fits our needs. We are using Classic version of Salesforce.

Business Case:
We generate hundreds of documents that need to be sent to different signatories based on certain conditions and once the signatories receive the doc, they need to select a value from a custom tag (dropdown) on the doc which will then be passed back to Salesforce.
Thanks to answers posted on SO, I know how I can [dynamically add recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262643/docusign-for-salesforce-custom-button-auto-populate-recipients) to a DocuSign doc and also how I can [pass values from Custom Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570755/automated-check-box-population-within-salesforce-from-checking-a-box-w-in-docusi) back to Salesforce.

However is it possible to dynamically prepopulate documents with one or more updateable custom fields or does it have to be manually dragged and dropped onto the document each time we send the doc over? 
Any pointers/references to documentation would really be appreciated.

Comment: Since its not explicitly clear, are you trying to create this logic on SalesForce?

Comment: DocuSign Customer Support told you to get your support here? Are they paying Stack Overflow for this support?

Comment: @JM-AGMS, **if** it's possible to create this logic in Salesforce and if I can get some guidance, I would love to give that a shot. My gut feel was that it would probably be using Javascript (just like the code that they have for dynamically adding recipients) because from what I understand, this bit of adding custom tag is happening within DocuSign and before the baton is passed back to Salesforce, but I could be way off base here. Thanks!

Comment: @kismert, I am not a DocuSign customer at this point and we are only evaluating to see if this meets our business needs, so I am not sure if that's why they directed me to SO, but yup that's what they said.

Comment: @StayinHungryNFoolish, I'm a little surprised that DocuSign's sales department would be OK with a potential customer being told to get unpaid support from "whoever" on the internet. May I suggest talking to sales, and see if they can give you the information you need to make a fair evaluation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the API documentation (below), it does look like its possible to add dynamic tabs. There is limited information on wether they can be updated, but I would suggest you try something like POSTMAN or any other REST API client that you can test this on.

Presumably, you can create this on SalesForce if you're inclined. Otherwise, you'll need to use some sever-side language to send the request.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs